# Mysql query not working with WHERE BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, where-clause, between

I was trying to get some data from my database, however I am currently only getting errors.

The query I am trying to do =

```
SELECT 
   count(id), 
   day(created_at), 
   year(created_at), 
   month(created_at) 
FROM 
   `orders` 
WHERE 
   day(created_at) = BETWEEN 1 AND 7 month(created_at) = 6 
   AND year(created_at) = 2014 
   AND company_id = 1 
group by 
   year(created_at), 
   month(created_at), 
   day(created_at)
```

The days between 1 and 7 will be the days sunday trough saturday to get all orders in that week.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what errors and where

Comment: It's simply `BETWEEN`, not `= BETWEEN`

Comment: Note for the future..... if you're asking a question because you're getting errors, it's useful to include the error message that you're getting in your question

Comment: And another note for future. Please format your question so it is readable

Comment: You could use `WHERE (created_at >= '2014-06-01' AND created_at < '2014-06-08')` so indexes can be used.

Comment: Sorry, I had to write it down quickyl. I'll format it next time, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   You have SQL Syntax errors , MISSING "AND" and "BETWEEN" not used correctly.
   Try the following:-


    SELECT COUNT(id), day(created_at), year(created_at), month(created_at)
    FROM  
   `orders`
    WHERE day(created_at)  BETWEEN 1 AND 7 
    AND  month(created_at) = 6 
    AND year(created_at) = 2014
    AND company_id = 1 
    GROUP BY year(created_at), month(created_at), day(created_at);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. this should be:

```
  SELECT count(id), day(created_at), year(created_at), month(created_at) 
      FROM `orders` WHERE day(created_at) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 
            AND month(created_at) = 6 AND year(created_at) = '2014' 
            AND company_id = 1 
        group by year(created_at), month(created_at), day(created_at)
```

You are using = and BETWEEN at same place which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(id), day(created_at), year(created_at), month(created_at) 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE day(created_at) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
AND month(created_at) = 6 
AND year(created_at) = 2014 
AND company_id = 1 
group by year(created_at), month(created_at), day(created_at)
```

The `AND` before `month(created_at)` as missed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is wrong near **month(created_at) =**

```
SELECT count(id),
       day(created_at),
       year(created_at),
       month(created_at)
FROM `orders`
WHERE day(created_at) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 
  AND month(created_at) = 6
  AND year(created_at) = 2014
  AND company_id = 1
GROUP BY year(created_at),
         month(created_at),
         day(created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

you must trim = from your query
 i write it for you again:

```
SELECT count(id), day(created_at), year(created_at), month(created_at) 
FROM `orders`
WHERE (day(created_at) BETWEEN 1 AND 7)
AND (month(created_at) = 6)
AND (year(created_at) = 2014)
AND (company_id = 1)
group by year(created_at), month(created_at), day(created_at)
```